# Grep and replace form content

Tags: regex, perl, replace, grep

Working on identifying and adjusting form content entries.
I'm using grep to eliminate values in array when form is submitted:

```
# Get the input
read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

# The following zaps entire value containing the item(s) grepped.
  @OrigArray = split(/&/, $buffer);
  @pairs = grep(!/kartridgeclub|bubba.org|\.ru/i, @OrigArray);
```

but I'd prefer to identify which of the unwanted character sequences
was entered and also (regardless of which one was entered), include
a conditional statement which would produce unique "return page" 
text if any of the unwanted character sequences were submitted.

I cannot, I think, use simple substitution instead of grep since 
I need to replace the entire array element containing the unwanted characters.

In other words, user enters bunch-of-garbage-always-containing-some.org-with-ru
extension (or bubba.org, etc.) into a form field.  How do I identify which of
the phrases in the grep he entered?  And, then replace it with a phrase of my
choice (instead of just deleting it from the array) and produce a different
"Thank You" page for this user?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a module like `CGI` to process the form input?

Comment: Tues, May 15, 2012... Many thanks to everyone who has answered.  A weird server problem is preventing me from going forward just now but I want to thank you for all your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Cfreak's question is pragmatic: use CGI to process your form's input.  Use CGI's param function, examine your form's parameters for the "unwanted character sequences," and then make changes and/or branch accordingly--based upon what you've found.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use 5.010;

my $input_field = param('input_field');

given(lc $input_field) {
    when(/kartridgeclub/) {
        print 'kartridgeclub';
        # do something else
    }
    when(/bubba\.org\b/) {
        print 'bubba.org';
        # do something else
    }
    when(/\.ru\b/) {
        print '.ru';
        # do something else
    }
    when(/this|that/) {
        print 'this or that';
        # do something else
    }
    default {
        print 'Your entry seems OK.';
        # do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while i fully agree with the other post(s) that you're better off using CGI for this, i think this line should achieve what you want.

```
my %pairs = map { $_ => ($_ =~ /kartridgeclub|bubba.org|\.ru/i ? 'invalid' : 'valid')} @orig_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use grep. Use good old for-loops and write some code.

```
for my $i (0 .. $#OrigArray) {
    my $pair = $OrigArray[$i];
    if ($pair =~ m/whatever/) {
        # you're welcome to change $OrigArray[$i] here
    }
}
```